# How to force the writing of buffers onto disk?

Tags: files-and-directories, binary

Usually, buffering is good; except when you critically need to write data to disk.  Is there a way to force the writing of buffers onto disk?  (I'm using a binary file)

I believe a `Close[ ]` followed by `OpenAppend[ ]` would work but this seems like an overkill.